# HTML Decoding of Eval database column value in repeater of ASP.NET webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I am trying to get HTML encoded value(processed and input by responsive Text Editor control) from database and decode it to display as normal plain text in the webform page.

I am able to get the values with Eval method in the repeater like below

```
<p><%#Eval("Content")%></p>
```

It works perfectly fine. I further tried to shorten it with following code

```
<%#Eval("Content").ToString().Length >= 170 ? Eval("Content").ToString().Substring(0, 170) : Eval("Content").ToString()%>
```

Does the needful, provided Database value is plain text and not HTML encoded one, which i have recently added, thus it stopped working.

Hence, i wish to know if I can use this following code to decode the encoded

```
<%=System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()%>
```

I Have tried doing this but no joy, can someone help or correct me if the following code is wrong(i think)

```
<%=System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(#Eval("Content"))%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
<%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("Content")) %>
```

The `<%=` is equivalent to `Response.Write` whereas `<%#` is data binding syntax which is what you need in this case. Your hash prefix on the `Eval` call is not valid syntax.

This is a useful reference to explain the difference between the various ASP.NET inline server tags: http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it helped me to do exactly i asked for. However I am ending up in other problem after this is succesfull, I am actually trying to retrieve paragraphs which are fed through input control and some automatic classes have made ways in the paragraph, which is now haunting my blog slider

Comment: No problem. Would be great if you could mark this as the answer. Then if you need help with your additional issue just ask the question!